# Inconsistent results from Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I am using google places API to find the nearby establishments.

For a location with 200m radius we are getting 23 establishments but for the same location with 500m radius we are getting only 12 establishments.

How is this possible and what is the possible fix for this?

We are using the following link for our request:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=xxx,yyy&radius=500&type=bus_station|cafe|car_repair|pharmacy|campground|car_dealer|car_rental|cemetery|courthouse|embassy|finance|fire_station|funeral_home|hindu_temple|insurance_agency|locksmith|mosque|physiotherapist|place_of_worship|plumber|roofing_contractor|synagogue|veterinary_care|accounting|airport|amusement_park|aquarium|art_gallery|atm|bakery|bank|bar|beauty_salon|bicycle_store|book_store|bowling_alley|car_wash|casino|church|city_hall|clothing_store|convenience_store|dentist|department_store|doctor|electrician|electronics_store|florist|food|furniture_store|gas_station|general_contractor|grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hair_care|hardware_store|health|home_goods_store|hospital|jewelry_store|laundry|lawyer|library|liquor_store|local_government_office|lodging|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|movie_rental|movie_theater|moving_company|museum|night_club|painter|park|parking|pet_store|police|post_office|real_estate_agency|restaurant|rv_park|school|shoe_store|shopping_mall|spa|stadium|storage|subway_station|taxi_stand|train_station|transit_station|travel_agency|university|zoo&key=zzzz

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests): "type — Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. **Only one type may be specified** ". Why do expect correct results from incorrect request?